# Sony Vaio dead keyboard

Tags: keyboard, sony-vaio

I have strange problem with my almost new laptop.
After I leave it turned on for some hours and return to use it, it was printing
something like ^[[2~ on the screen and I cannot stop it. After rebooting
it did not show any activity. After a few hours I managed to turn it on
by hitting random keys on the keyboard. It starts that way but I have to use an
external keyboard to type anything. When I randomly stroke the keys when it is
turned on, it sometimes prints unrecognised characters. It works the same
way in Linux and Windows (Ubuntu, Windows 7).

What can be the reason it started to work so strangely and is there any way
to fix it without sending it to warranty and waiting few weeks? 
I don't remember getting it wet, but there could be something like cigarette ashes in it.

Comment: You may not lose your laptop for weeks if you are willing to replace the keyboard yourself. Some companies (Dell & HP for 2) are happy to send the keyboard out and then talk you through the replacement.

Comment: If there's likely cigarette ash and possibly other substances in it, could easily just be stuff on the contacts. You can clean it yourself if so: Google for a disassembly guide for your laptop to lift the keyboard out and carefully clean it with a small amount of soapy water. Leave to dry for at least 24hrs before you put it back.